# Handlebars layout include js and css

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

What is the best way in terms of performace to include css and js files in the layout.hbs file(main layout). Is better to include all the css files of your app or to send an object as parameter with which files to be loaded like this?

```
  router.get('/',function(req,res){
    let css = [{css:'/css/style.css'}]
    let scripts = [{script:'/javascript/javascript.js'}];
    res.render('index',{scripts:scripts,style:css})
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

Loading a minimal collection of CSS and JS on a per-page basis *may* make a page load for a specific page faster (so long as the savings in total data aren't outweighed by the overhead of additional HTTP requests).

On the other hand, loading everything up front allows it to be cached.

Which is best depends on if you value the loading speed of the initial page over the average loading speed and on how many different pages on your site the average visitor visits.

This ignores *developer* performance with the relative impacts of the work needed to filter the CSS and JS for each page vs issues caused by having code shared between pages leading to (for example) conflicts of HTML class names.